# Laravel Voyager Admin: How to sort items in sidebar

Tags: laravel, sorting, admin, items, voyager

my question is es the title sais.

Is there a possibility to sort in Voyager Admin the sidebar-items?
I already did some research but couldnt find an answer.

Thanks in advance
Greetings Mickey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i found the answer, its really easy:

In Voyager Admin go to Tools->MenuBuilder->Builder (on the menu-type you wanna sort)

Here you can sort your Menu-Items per Drag&Drop

Greetings Mickey